# Python. Разбить строку по точкам, игнорируя точки в описании даты. Т.е. надо после точки сделать "с новой строки", игнорируя точки в дате

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, методы

Всем привет.
Дан текст типа:"Внимание.Планируются профилактические работы.Они будут проведены 30.01.2023.Обращайтесь за справками"
Надо: каждое предложение (после точки) с новой строки.
Я решаю это методом str.replace('.', '\n), но тогда разрываются цифры даты.
Тогда я решил ввести цикл с условием:

```
for i in range(0, len(str)):
   if str[i] == '.' and str[i+1].isalpha():
    str = str.replace('.', '\n')
```

но всё равно цифры рвёт.
Какой подход посоветуете?
что я делаю не так?

Comment: регулярные выражения посоветую.

Comment: посоветую осознать, что ``str.replace('.', '\n')`` заменяет ВСЕ точки в строке, независимо от того, что вы там написали в условии. Не ту точку, которая была проверена в условии, а абсолютно все точки, от первой до последней. Т.е. имея ``str.replace('.', '\n')`` можно никакое условие и не писать, оно ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Попробуйте такое регулярное выражение `(?<!\..{1})(?<!\..{2})\.(?!.{1,2}\.)` не ставим перенос, если через 1 или 2 символа есть точка перед или после точки

Answer (score 1):

Решено с помощью регулярных выражений так:

```
import re

text = "Внимание.Планируются профилактические работы.Они будут проведены 30.01.2023.Обращайтесь за справками"

pattern = r'([.])([\D])'
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\1\n\2", text)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай перебор букв и если буква будет Заглавной савь "/n".

```
stroke = "Внимание.Планируются профилактические работы.Они будут проведены 30.01.2023.Обращайтесь за справками"
strokeexit = ""


for i in stroke:
    if i.isupper():
        strokeexit+="\n"
    strokeexit+=i
print(strokeexit)
```

В таком случае вывод:

[image: python output]

Comment: Не всегда это правильно. Вдруг в строке будут какие-то названия или имена.

Comment: Тогда добавить ещё 1 проверку что пред символ "."

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - .[^(\d{2,2}.(\d{2,2}|\d{2,4}))] - чтобы за "." не следовала последовательность из 2 цифр + точка + 2 или 4 цифры